# IF statement for date checker ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggling with an assignment, trying to get my code to check that the end date must be a later date than the start date in ASP.NET in C#. The teacher says:

> Create an If statement to check that both start and end date exist as COMPOUND condition. Hint: use &&. Inside this if statement (check date-difference)

Here's what I have:

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(Request["txtStartDate"]);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(Request["txtEndDate"]);
    if (DateTime.Compare(startDate, endDate) > 0)
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        lblError.Text += "The end date must be a later date than the start date.";
        //The Msg text will be displayed in lblError.Text after all the error messages are concatenated
        bIsFormValid = false;
        //Boolean value - test each textbox to see if the data entered is valid, if not set validState=false. 
        //If after testing each validation rule, the validatedState value is true, then submit to frmPersonnelVerified.aspx, if not, then display error message
    }
    else
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }


    // Redirect the User to frmStudentConfirmed.aspx
    if (bIsFormValid)
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Clear();
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Miguel

Comment: Sounds like your error is in the call to `Parse`, not in the comparison. Make sure to check the string in `Request["txtStartDate"]` and `Request["txtEndDate"]` and see if `Parse` knows how to to parse them into DateTime objects.

Comment: can't get more clear than this --> "Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". but yeah @yeedle has mentioned what you should look out for.

Comment: You should add to your question what value you are passing in your textStartDate and txtEndDate. After that I'm sure we can point you to how to parse the datetime correctly.

Comment: Date(s) send in request (GET method) is/are not in right format.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the problem is with the format of the dates you are trying to pass in

```
Request["txtStartDate"]
```

or

```
Request["txtEndDate"]
```

DateTime.Prase static method accept number of formats by default check 
https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse

if for some reason you need to pass a the date in a different format try using

DateTime.ParseExact
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx